# Direction of Coriolis Acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors, coriolis-effect

I read in a textbook that the Coriolis acceleration will deflect an eastward-moving object towards the south and north for a westward-moving object. However, when I work out the cross products myself, I find that the Coriolis acceleration has components in the $y$- and $z$-directions when it should just be the $y$-direction. Where am I making a mistake?

For an eastward-moving object
$$a_{C}=-2\omega \times v$$
$$=-2(\omega \cos \lambda \hat{k}+\omega \sin \lambda \hat{\jmath}) \times v\hat{\imath}$$
$$=-2v \omega \cos \lambda \hat{\jmath} +2v \omega \sin \lambda \hat{k}.$$

However this seems to indicate that the object will have some acceleration away from the surface of the earth which can't be right. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Coriolis exists because an object tends to move in a straight line and from a rotating point of view the line would appear to "tear-off" the surface of the earth.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct. It is the first sentence that is not universally valid.

Let's say that the Earth is a sphere with radius $R$ at origin, rotating with angular velocity $\vec{\omega} = (0, 0, \omega)$. Now consider an object moving eastward (that is, $\dot{\vec{x}} = (v, 0, 0)$) over the equator (at $\vec{x} = (0, R, 0)$). Locally, $\hat{x}$ points east, $\hat{y}$ up and $\hat{z}$ to the north.

Then
$$
    \ddot{\vec{x}} = -2 \vec{\omega} \times \dot{\vec{x}}
    = -2 (0, 0, \omega) \times (v, 0, 0) = (0, 2 \omega v, 0) = 2 \omega v \hat{y}.
$$

At $\vec{x}$ this points straight up: the Coriolis force is trying to pull the object away from the surface, with no horizontal components. From an inertial point of view, the object tries to keep moving on a straight tangent line, while the Earth's surface is curved down, around its centre.

Except at the poles there will always be a component pointing away from the surface; and at the poles it is not possible to move "eastward" or "westward" at all.